# How to retrieve a column label in a vector returned by a function

Tags: r, function, label

I have a working function that returns a list of stats regarding a column, but I can't get it to also return the column name.

```
attach(ChickWeight)

frequency<-function(X1){  #returns n, mean, SD, min, 25%, median, 75%, max, like EPI Info
  
  X<-(as.numeric(unlist(X1))) # if factor or table reference fix to return correctly
  c(sum(X!="",na.rm=TRUE),mean(X,na.rm=TRUE), sd(X,na.rm=TRUE),fivenum(X,na.rm=TRUE)) }

frequency(ChickWeight[, 1])
frequency (Chick)


# Above works correctly.  Now I modify the function by adding labels(X1) to the vector returned...and no luck!

frequency2<-function(X1){  #returns label, n, mean, SD, min, 25%, median, 75%, max, like EPI Info
  
  X<-(as.numeric(unlist(X1))) 
  c(labels(X1),sum(X!="",na.rm=TRUE),mean(X,na.rm=TRUE),sd(X,na.rm=TRUE),fivenum(X,na.rm=TRUE)) }

frequency2(weight) # should print same frequency but with column label first
frequency2(ChickWeight[, 1])
```

Surely there must be something else I need to put into the place of labels(X1) to retrieve the column name and use it as a row name.

Thanks for your help!